# How to calculate distance from the International Space Station given coordinates?

Tags: geometry, algorithms

How would one calculate how far away a point is (latitude/longitude) from the international space station given its latitude/longitude/altitude? The distance would be direct as if drawing a straight line from the two points, even if on the other side of the Earth.

Comment: Maybe convert your location and the location of ISS into rectangular coordinates?

Comment: If you want it to be very precise, you also need to know the radius of Earth at both points. IOW distance from the center of Earth rather than the altitude.

Answer (score 2):

If $r$ is the distance from the Earth's centre, $\phi$ is the longitude in radians (increasing from zero at Greenwich as one goes eastwards) and $\theta$ is the
latitude in radians (increasing from zero at the Equator as one goes northwards), then
the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates are given by:

$$p(r,\phi, \theta) = r(\cos \phi \cos \theta, \cos \phi \sin \theta, \sin \phi)$$

Given two sets of coordinates $(r_k,\phi_k, \theta_k)$, the distance is given
by $\|p(r_1,\phi_1, \theta_1)-p(r_2,\phi_2, \theta_2)\|$.

In your case, we can take $r_1=R$, $r_2=R+A$, where $R$ is the radius of the Earth (I'm assuming a nice sphere, of course) and $A$ is the altitude of the
station above the surface of the Earth.

Comment: in your equation, what is the p in p(r,ϕ,θ) as well as k in (rk,ϕk,θk)?

Comment: $p$ is a function $p:[0,\infty) \times [0,2 \pi] \times [-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^3$. The $k$ is $1$ or $2$ and just selects one of a pair of coordinates.

Comment: That just gave me more questions =/ haha. If you have the time, could you provide an example using lat/long/alt with your first answers equations? I think that would help me understand the equation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are having issues with. Just substitute the various values in and compute. The radius of the Earth is about 6,400km, the ISS is about 400km above the surface, so $r_1 =6400, r_2 = 6800$. Then substitute the longitudes & latitudes (in radians) to compute the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of the two points and then compute the Euclidean distance between the two points.